# Find string from xpath which contains tag as child elements In Java

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling, for-xml-path

I have following part of XML code and I want to get string from specific tag.

Input XML:

```
<subject>
   <title> this title has 5 <sup>+</sup> rating star </title>
</subject>
```

From the above XML I want a string using xpath like

Expected output:

```
"this title has 5+ rating star"
```

Note: I have used @XmlPath like

```
@XmlPath('subject/title/text()')
private String title;
```

But it returns second value as result in title variable like "rating star"

Comment: Sure, but where is your attempt?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat i am facing issue is like if main tag contains sub tag then it returns last part of the string as result and override first part .

Comment: Please help me to resolve the above issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is precisely why people advise against using text() unless you have very specialized requirements. The XPath function string() applied to a node returns the string value of the node, which for an element is the concatenation of all the contained text, ignoring markup - which is exactly what you are looking for. So you want `string(subject/title)`. If you're using a Java API note that the result will now be a string, not a node-set.

Comment: Actually I am using xpath as an annotation like..  **@XmlPath("subject/title/text()")**  
   private String title;

Comment: I don't think data binding works very will with mixed content (but others may not agree).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try `string(subject/title)`. I don't have access to Java for the time being but the string operation is common enough in XPath. It is supposed to concatenate text content without traces of any elements.

Comment: Perhaps something like: ‘’’XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression = "//Subject/string(Title)";
nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);’’’